# Remote Connect to a Server through internet?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, remote-access, connection

I do know how to connect remotely to another Server running Windows Server 2003 on my network. But what i would like to know is..........can i connect to another Server through the internet? If YES.....how can i do this?

I am sitting in South Africa. Our Head office is in USA. I need to connect to a Server there in order to create/change/update items on that Server.

Thanks in advanced!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option would be set up a VPN back to your network in the USA. This will allow you to remote into any machine just as if you were on the network.

A less secure option would be to just set up port forwarding on the USA router to point to the machine you want to remote into.

An even less secure option, if all else fails, you can use something like [goto my pc.](https://www.gotomypc.com/) (I actually haven't used this service, so I can't really comment on the security aspect of it, but since it involves a third party application, I think it would be less secure of all options -- I could be wrong, but I wouldn't bet on it if it was a production server.)

Answer (score 2):

You'd either need to open up port 3389 (RDC) on your USA location's firewall & forward port 3389 requests the the USA server's internal IP address, which isn't very secure, or establish a VPN tunnel into the USA location's subnet & simply allow RDC connections locally.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but agree don't forward all RDP traffic from the outside, but setup a VPN and do it from an "LAN IP Address"

Answer (score 0):

If your office is expecting to remote into another office server on your own network, why would you want to go through the internet? If its on the same network you should just be able to use RDP regularly. If you're not on the network check with your sysadmins about a VPN connection.

Answer (score 0):

Both your outbound firewall/router and the firewall/router on the other end (the server you are trying to connect to) needs to allow the correct port for remote access.  By default this is port 3389 although you can change this.

The other option is if you have a VPN set up to the remote office, (which will be more secure anyway) then you connect to the VPN and you should be able use RDP to connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

A little more information is needed here I think. How do you now connect to the server? Why not use a VPN if you’re not on a WAN connection. I would not recommend for security reasons that you open a server to the internet for remote administration. If you are connected to the network via VPN then you can get to the server the same way you would if you were in the office.

Answer (score 0):

If this type of management is going to be common, and you require access to multiple servers with multiple users, you may want to consider Terminal Services Gateway.

Its a feature only available in Windows Server 2008, and it allows a TS Gateway server to serve requests to internal resources, across a secure channel.

Answer (score 0):

RDC will do this...should do this.  ALso IntelliAdmin Internet Edition will do it.

http://www.intelliadmin.com/RemoteControlPro_Manual.htm

Answer (score 0):

If this is a temporary solution you need, and don't have the time/inclination to set up a VPN, Webex is pretty good. You can check it out, [here](http://www.webex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For a "cheapo" solution, I would actually recommend something like GOTOMYPC.com .  I say this based on the assumption that you are new to doing remote administration.

Someething like gotomypc is easy enough to setup and will be secure enough in the interim that you can use it while deploying a better corporate solution such as a VPN or SSL VPN or secure terminal services.

They have a 30 day trial so no money spent for a quick interim solution.

EDIT:  oops didn't see Bob's post regarding gotomypc